# STM32 ISR routine hanging inside of cmsis-OS osThreadFlagSet()

Tags: stm32, freertos, isr, cmsis

I have a strange issue with interactions between cmsis OS thread flags and interrupt service routines on an STM32G070.

When calling osThreadFlagsSet() from a GPIO rising edge interrupt, the entire program hangs inside of configASSERT() within tasks.c [line 4853] of the FreeRTOS software

```
/* The task should not have been on an event list. */
configASSERT( listLIST_ITEM_CONTAINER( &( pxTCB->xEventListItem ) ) == NULL );
```

With this processor, none of the solutions online fixed this.

I tried:

- Setting the NVIC priority grouping (not available or defined for the G070)
- Changing all of the task priorities
- Increasing stack / heap allocation

For some odd reason, my answer below fixed it. If anyone wants to comment on WHY this may have fixed it, feel free. I'm posting this here in case some other poor soul finds this on a search engine.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by changing the .stack_size variable within the osThreadAttr_t structure for a completely unrelated thread which runs on a lower priority.

The CubeMX software defines a minimum stack size in words, and one of my tasks was the same as that minimum size (128 words). This caused no issues with anything else, but as soon as I changed it to 256 the osThreadFlagsSet() call for a different set of functions / threads worked properly.